# How can I improve programme which check if parenthesis is balanced?

Tags: swift, data-structures, stack

I have written a sample programme which checks if parenthesis are balanced. I tried to optimize it and this is the best I can come up. However I am looking if we can improved this further. I am also not sure if this is a valid question to put on stackoverflow. Any thoughts and suggestion

```
func checkBalancedParenthesis(parenthesis: String) -> (Bool,String) {

    var stack = Stack<Character>()

    for character in parenthesis.characters {

        guard let check = try? checkValidPattern(a: ("!",character)) else {

            return (false,"Pattern is not valid")
        }

        if let elem = stack.top, try! checkValidPattern(a: (elem,character)) {

            stack.pop()

        }
        else {
            stack.push(item: character)
        }
    }

    return (stack.isEmpty,stack.isEmpty ? "Balanced": "Un-Balanced")

}


func checkValidPattern(a: (Character,Character)) throws -> Bool {
    let validList: [Character] = ["(",")","[","]","}","{","<",">"]

    switch a
    {
    case ("(",")"):
        return true
    case ("[","]"):
        return true
    case ("{","}"):
        return true
    case ("<",">"):
        return true
    case let (_,char) where validList.contains(char) == true:
            return false
    default:
        throw InvalidPattern.chracterNotValid
    }
}
```

Comment: "if parenthesis are balanced"  What does that mean?  The word parenthesis is a singular noun.

Comment: If your program works as intended and you are looking for a review and possible improvements then codereview.stackexchange.com is the right site.

Comment: Compare also https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136514/swift-hackerrank-balanced-brackets

Comment: Note that if you do decide to post this at the code review site, delete this post.

Comment: Thanks everybody. @MartinR, thanks for pointing to the link. I think this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

might be my solution will be useful for someone. Check balance for brackets or not only for them.
func takes string and dict with matching character(or string if you need) cases and returns isBalanced(Bool). **Swift 3(4)**.

For Swift 4: "str.characters" replace to "str".

### Here is it:

```
func isBalanced(str: String, dictAccordance: [Character : Character]) -> Bool {
    var balArr: [Character] = []

    let keys = dictAccordance.keys // all keys (opening characters)
    let values = dictAccordance.values // all values (closing characters)

    for char in str.characters {

        switch char {
            // met char from keys. (Met opening character)
        case (let key) where keys.contains(char):
            balArr.append(key)

            // met char from values. (Met closing character)
        case (let value) where values.contains(char):
            let lastOpenedCharKey = balArr.removeLast() // key  of char
            // check last matching
            if dictAccordance[lastOpenedCharKey] != value {
                return false
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    return balArr.isEmpty
}
```

**Usage:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dictAccordance: [Character : Character] = [
        "(" : ")",
        "[" : "]",
        "{" : "}",
        "<" : ">"  // put dict whatever you want
    ]

    let test1 = isBalanced(str: "sdvs", dictAccordance: dictAccordance)
    let test2 = isBalanced(str: "()", dictAccordance: dictAccordance)
    let test3 = isBalanced(str: "[]<<>>", dictAccordance: dictAccordance)
    let test4 = isBalanced(str: "kn(jdnsv;)ds[svds]dvs", dictAccordance: dictAccordance)
    let test5 = isBalanced(str: "(dacadc[])", dictAccordance: dictAccordance)
    let test6 = isBalanced(str: "([) ewf]", dictAccordance: dictAccordance)
    let test7 = isBalanced(str: "[ (()]", dictAccordance: dictAccordance)

    let arrTest = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7]

    print(arrTest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get what you actually need. You could use a `for` loop that checks for each character in the sequence. Append every opening bracket into a new array. For every closing bracket check if the last bracket in new array is the opening bracket corresponding to the closing bracket then remove the opening bracket. Keep this until the end of array, check if array is empty. Enumerate the brackets for type safety. You could check this link for more code in code review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136514/swift-hackerrank-balanced-brackets).

Comment: Counting is not enough to detect ’[{]}` as unbalanced.

Comment: yes you are right. Need, much more than this. I too found the link for perfect swift solution in codereview. Maybe I could add the add the link for others in future.